# metpy import issue in Debian 10

Tags: python-3.x, metpy

I am running python3 on a Debian 10 (buster) system.

Up until yesterday, I was able to perform this import:

`from metpy.plots import (StationPlot, StationPlotLayout, wx_code_map, current_weather)`

After a general package update, I can no longer perform the import and instead get this string of errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):  File
> "/home/disk/bob/impacts/bin/ASOS_plot_data_hourly_ISU.py", line 37, in
>     from metpy.plots import (StationPlot, StationPlotLayout,
> wx_code_map, current_weather)  File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/metpy/**init**.py", line 35, in
>     from .xarray import *  # noqa: F401, F403, E402  File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/metpy/xarray.py", line 27, in 
> from .units import DimensionalityError, UndefinedUnitError, units
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/metpy/units.py", line 40, in
>     lambda string: string.replace('%', 'percent')  File
> "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pint/registry.py", line 74, in
> **call**    obj = super(_Meta, self).**call**(*args, **kwargs) TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument
> 'preprocessors'

In fact, I can't even do a simple

import metpy

without getting the same error chain.

Obviously, there must be some sort of version discrepancy with xarray or some other package.

I currently have these versions installed: 1.0.0rc1.po of metpy and 0.12.1-1 of xarray.

Any thoughts about what the required combination of packages should be or who I might ask about this?

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear from your post what versions of Pint and Python you have installed. From the error, it seems like you are having problems with too old a version of Pint installed, though MetPy 1.0.0rc1 *should* have had support to deal with that. Really, the whole `1.0.0rc1.po` version makes me wonder almost if MetPy was installed from git at some point after rc1?

Regardless, MetPy 1.0.0rc1, which means that was the first *Release Candidate* for the 1.0 release of MetPy and is not a version I would rely upon. I would suggest updating to either MetPy 1.0.1 (if you are using Python 3.6) or MetPy 1.2 (for Python >= 3.7).

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  This was indeed a problem with pint.  I had version 0.9 installed.  When I bumped that up to v0.18, things seemed to work.  I will install MetPy 1.2 (since I'm working with python3.7) and hope things continue to work out